# Starting Elassandra - Cassandra with Elasticsearch failing with path.home is not configured

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, elassandra

Starting Cassandra with Elasticsearch getting following error in ~/logs/system.log

```sh
./bin/cassandra -e
```

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: path.home is not configured
        at org.elasticsearch.env.Environment.<init>(Environment.java:97)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.InternalSettingsPreparer.prepareEnvironment(InternalSettingsPreparer.java:85)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.InternalSettingsPreparer.prepareEnvironment(InternalSettingsPreparer.java:66)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:246)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.ElassandraDaemon.activate(ElassandraDaemon.java:181)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.ElassandraDaemon.main(ElassandraDaemon.java:548)
```

Answer (score 0):

set env variables in .bashrc (ubuntu)or .zshrc(Mac)

```
export CASSANDRA_HOME=<your Elassandra downloads path>/elassandra-6.2.3.31
export CASSANDRA_CONF=<your Elassandra downloads path>//elassandra-6.2.3.31/conf
```